# Delete photos with no location in EXIF information

Tags: qgis, photos

I can extract the locations of my photos in QGIS using Photo2Shape or Geotag and import photos, but I want to be able to delete the photos that do not have location information with them (they are backed up elsewhere).

At the moment I have to look in the attribute table which photos get imported with a latitude and longitude value of 0. Then I have to find these files manually and delete them. This is very time consuming and it would be great if it was possible to do this automatically somehow.

I guess a another possible workaround would be for the photos that have locations to be copied to a sub folder.

I just wondered if anyone knew of a tool (GIS or otherwise) that could achieve this before I set about writing a script to do it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this in the Python console:

```
import os
layer.setSubsetString('"latitude" = 0 AND "longitude" = 0')
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    path = feature['path']
    try:
        os.remove(path)
    except IOError:
        print "Can't delete {}".format(path)
layer.setSubsetString('')
```

We use `layer.setSubsetString()` just to reduce the features to only `0,0` ones.  You could also loop each feature and check for `0,0` but this is simple enough.

[image]

Comment: This worked really well, thanks Nathan. Just need to add a line to delete the record from the table as well. Maybe it would be good to have this as an option in one of the photo import plugins?

Comment: When using with the Photo2Shape plugin, the path field is 'filepath', not 'path' just incase anyone has problems with that.

Comment: Feel free to update my code on here.  I was just going from memory.

Answer (score 0):

this script might help you in making a python script to do the task, instead of writing you can read :

```
def set_gps_location(file_name, lat, lng):
    """Adds GPS position as EXIF metadata

    Keyword arguments:
    file_name -- image file
    lat -- latitude (as float)
    lng -- longitude (as float)

    """
    lat_deg = to_deg(lat, ["S", "N"])
    lng_deg = to_deg(lng, ["W", "E"])

    print lat_deg
    print lng_deg

    # convert decimal coordinates into degrees, munutes and seconds
    exiv_lat = (pyexiv2.Rational(lat_deg[0]*60+lat_deg[1],60),pyexiv2.Rational(lat_deg[2]*100,6000), pyexiv2.Rational(0, 1))
    exiv_lng = (pyexiv2.Rational(lng_deg[0]*60+lng_deg[1],60),pyexiv2.Rational(lng_deg[2]*100,6000), pyexiv2.Rational(0, 1))

    exiv_image = pyexiv2.ImageMetadata(file_name)
    exiv_image.read()
    exif_keys = exiv_image.exif_keys

    exiv_image["Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitude"] = exiv_lat
    exiv_image["Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLatitudeRef"] = lat_deg[3]
    exiv_image["Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLongitude"] = exiv_lng
    exiv_image["Exif.GPSInfo.GPSLongitudeRef"] = lng_deg[3]
    exiv_image["Exif.Image.GPSTag"] = 654
    exiv_image["Exif.GPSInfo.GPSMapDatum"] = "WGS-84"
    exiv_image["Exif.GPSInfo.GPSVersionID"] = '2 0 0 0'
    exiv_image.write()
```